# Closest point in a given subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space (not necessarily Banach) and let $\{v_1,... v_n\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $X$. For fixed $y \in X$, I'm to show that there are scalars $a_i$ minimizing

$$\left\| y - \sum_{j=1}^n a_jv_j \right\|,$$

and then if $X$ is strictly normed I'm to show that this choice of scalars is unique. This looks a lot like the Hilbert projection theorem except I'm in a general normed space. I played around with treating the expression as a linear functional on $\mathbb{C}^n$, but it seems like it's more work than should be needed. Can I simply modify the proof of the Hilbert projection theorem or does that statement depend on the space being Hilbert (either for the inner product or the completeness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A finite dimensional subspace of any vector space is convex (by the definition of subspace) and [closed](http://planetmath.org/everyfinitedimensionalsubspaceofanormedspaceisclosed).